# Disable and Enable button according to certain conditions

Tags: android, button, real-time

I'm relatively new to android programming . Currently using eclipse and I have a problem .

I'm asked to code a button called clockin , whereby this button will check if "Allow non-working site" to clock in . Meaning to say that when opening up this application , this button will automatically check if it allows non-working site . If it allows , it will do authentication , if not it will check its distance between the worksite and current location . If within range , enable button , if not disable the button .

This may sound rather complex but I'm task to do this ASAP .

The code I have is as follow :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

EditText txtusername;
EditText txtpassword;
Button btnclockin;
Button btnclockout;
GPSTracker gps;


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    txtusername=(EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.username);
    txtpassword=(EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.password);
    btnclockin=(Button)this.findViewById(R.id.clockin);
    btnclockout=(Button)this.findViewById(R.id.clockout);
    btnclockin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

if((txtusername.getText().toString()).equals(txtpassword.getText().toString())){

Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy   hh:mm");
String strdate1 = sdf1.format(c1.getTime());

TextView txtdate1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
txtdate1.setText(strdate1);

gps = new GPSTracker(MainActivity.this);

// check if GPS enabled
if(gps.canGetLocation()){

    double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
    double longitude = gps.getLongitude();

    // \n is for new line
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have clock in succesfully at \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}else{
    // can't get location
    // GPS or Network is not enabled
    // ask user to enable GPS/Network in settings
    gps.showSettingsAlert();

}
   } else{
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Invalid Username//Password",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }

}
}) ;     



btnclockout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if((txtusername.getText().toString()).equals(txtpassword.getText().toString())){

        Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("d/M/yy h:m a");
        String strdate1 = sdf1.format(c1.getTime());

        TextView txtdate1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        txtdate1.setText(strdate1);

        gps = new GPSTracker(MainActivity.this);

        // check if GPS enabled
        if(gps.canGetLocation()){


            double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
            double longitude = gps.getLongitude();


            // \n is for new line
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have clocked out successfully at \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{
            // can't get location
            // GPS or Network is not enabled
            // ask user to enable GPS/Network in settings
            gps.showSettingsAlert();

        }

           } else{
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Invalid Username//Password",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }





};
});
} 


}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this `yourButton.setEnabled(true);` `true` if the condition is met, else `false`. If needed you might wanna add this `yourButton.setClickable(true);`.

Comment: Do you happen to know the code for the condition too ? Cause I don't have coding background . Hence, I'm really weak in this .

Comment: your stated problem is not very clear, maybe try to add some diagram that'll explain the whole problem.

Comment: I try to explain cause I can't put a diagram over here as its confidential. What I need now is a attendance taking application. Whereby the UI has Username, Password and 2 buttons. Which is clock in and out. In the clock in button, the button is suppose to check whether the settings configured allows "non-worksite". Mean to say that the user can clock in anywhere and the Geopoint is recorded into the database. If the settings allow, it proceed to authenticate the user and send its geopoint to the server. If it does not allow, check the distance between the worksite and current to see if allow.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (condition) {
    btn.setEnabled(true);
    btn.setOnClickListner(new ViewOnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View v) {
            // your code here
        }
    });
} else {
    btn.setEnabled(false);
}
```